# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jqxLoader is not a function - ACTUALIZADO

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo la siguiente vista parcial en ASP.net MVC 5 `$('#jqxLoader').jqxLoader('open');` me devuelve mensaje de error (DEL TITULO). Me parece que es porque mi `PartialView` se carga por Ajax en forma asícrona y desactiva la librería de JS que requiere para poder ejecutar lo que necesito.

He intentado utilizando `defer` pero sigo sin resolver el inconveniente..

Esta vista parcial la estoy cargando por Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                  url: '@Url.Action("Cargar_pViewDetalle", "Ventas")',
                  method: "GET",
                  data: { 'ti_docu': tipo_docu },
                  contentType: 'application/json',
                  success: function (response) {
                      $('#Cargar_ViewDetalle').html(response);
                  },
                  error: function (errormessage) {
                      console.log(errormessage);
                  },
                  async: true
              });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: mvc]

```
<script defer src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxloader.js" type="mod"></script>

<fieldset class="form-horizontal intercaladoBottom">
    <div class="row intercaladoBottom">
        @Html.Label("Nro Secuencia", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nu_secu_ingreso, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center  box-fDesactivado", @Value = Model.Nu_secu_ingreso, @readonly = true })
    </div>

    <div class="row intercaladoBottom">
        @Html.Label("Importe del Ingreso", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2 text-ingresar" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Im_ingreso, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-1 text-center", @Value = Model.Im_ingreso, @readonly = true, @type = "number", min = "0", step = "0.0001" })
    </div>

    <div class="row intercaladoBottom">
        @Html.Label("Observación", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2 text-ingresar" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.De_ingreso, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-5 width-maximo", @Value = Model.De_ingreso, @readonly = true })

    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Tienes [jquery](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jquerybasics/jquerybasics.htm?search=) en el proyecto?

Comment: Si funciona sin problema lo he utilizado en otras vistas parciales y sin problemas, cuando desactivo la vista parcial para que no cargue la librería load se carga sin inconvenientes.

Comment: Es una vista parcial donde tienes eso escrito?

Comment: Así es y se carga por Ajax, acabo de adjuntar el código Ajax que ejecuta la vista parcial, será porque no se está cargando la librería? porque he notado que el problema viene cuando imprimo la vista parcial.

Comment: como el documento es externo no pinta el valor de  `'@Url.Action("Cargar_pViewDetalle", "Ventas")'` por lo que intenta abrirlo de forma literal....

Comment: Disculpa que vuelva a preguntar pero como sería ese procedimiento? recién estoy conociendo y comenzando a trabajar con Ajax y JS

Comment: has probado a poner el jquery desde la view en vez de desde la Partial?

Comment: quítale el "defer " a ese script y colócalo en el header antes que renderize el body